# Маска для 9?979*8

Tags: python, python-3.x, re, маска

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но не могу понять, как написать регулярное выражение для этой маски, сколько ни искал... ? - одна любая цифра, * - любая последовательность цифр произвольной длины или также пустая последовательность

```py
re.match("9.979\d*8"...
```

```py
import re
a1 = 909798
a = 0
if a1%50068!=0:
    a = a1 + 50068 - a1%50068
m = 9_997_999_998
for i in range(a, m, 50068):
    if re.match("9.979\d*8", str(i)) and (str(i).count('0')>0):
        print(i, i//50068)
```

В конце строки должна быть цифра "8", а ее в некоторых строках нет

```
9097906348 
9197992280 
9297928008 
9297978076 
9397913804
```

Comment: `\d` - одна любая цифра, `\d*` нуль или более цифр

Comment: Почему-то в конце строки "8" может и не быть

Comment: ограничить начало и конец надо `^9\d979\d*8$`

Comment: спасибо. как раз недавно дошло)